# I18n using wrong locale in emails, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, actionmailer

I'm using Rails 2.3.6 and I18n.  Everything works fine except that I18n is using the wrong locale when sending emails.  In fact it renders the following code using en.yml instead of it.yml, although my default locale is it.

Can you help me?

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  default_url_options[:host] = GAME_CONFIG["domain"]

  def password_reset_instructions(user)  
    subject       I18n.translate("email_messages.lost_password.subject")  
    from  "#{GAME_CONFIG["name"]} <no-reply@#{GAME_CONFIG["domain"]}>"
    recipients    user.email  
    sent_on       Time.now  
    body          :edit_password_reset_url => edit_password_reset_url(user.perishable_token)
  end

end
```

In my production server if I try to check for the current locale I get:

```
I18n.default_locale
:it
I18n.locale
:it
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that this is normal behavior and I can fix this specifing :locale => ":it"

Comment: Where do you specify this please?

Comment: every time you call the I18n method.  For example I18n.translate("email_messages.lost_password.subject", :locale => ":it")